# jQuery: Element Not Resizing On Page Load

Tags: jquery

I'm having issues with getting an element to resize itself on page load. It works find when the browser viewport is resized(it adjusts), but just not on page load. Upon page load, the height of the element is 0px.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  var imgWidth = $(".flexslider li img").width();
  var imgHeight = $(".flexslider li img").height();
  $('.flex-caption-viewport').width(imgWidth).height(imgHeight)
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  var imgWidth = $(".flexslider li img").width();
  var imgHeight = $(".flexslider li img").height();
  $('.flex-caption-viewport').width(imgWidth).height(imgHeight)
});
```

You can see the issue live with the theme I'm working on [HERE](http://xarpixels-revitalize-template.blogspot.com/).

I have tried many things, including .ready function, and selecting a different element in which to match the size to. The goal is for the element to resize(be responsive) to match the size of the image that it overlay's.

Comment: On load, is your object present on the page? Try doing a console.log of $(".flexslider li img")

Comment: Use console logs to find when you're getting that width. The element might not have been rendered properly yet so the width would be zero.

Comment: Width is not the problem, it's the height. The element is present, and is the correct height. I will try a console.log. Never done one before, so give me some time to figure it out.

Comment: I just realized that I use the console.log all the time. The dimensions of all elements are as they should be, except the one I'm trying to resize via jquery.

Comment: I think it has something to do with when everything is loaded. I tried  moving the script to be last on the DOM, but it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the height isn't available on window load. That is probably due to flexslider not being done initializing on window load. Run `$(".flex-viewport").height();` in your console after the page has been loaded to see that height is zero. I suggest using the start api callback for flexslider. Which should look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
      start: function(slider) {
        var imgWidth = $(".flexslider li img").width();
        var imgHeight = $(".flexslider li img").height();
        $('.flex-caption-viewport').width(imgWidth).height(imgHeight)
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I got this tip from the flexslider web site [here](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) under the section titled "The new, robust Callback API"

Answer (score 1):

You can try to trigger the resize event, instead of resizing your things `onload`.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var imgWidth = $(".flexslider li img").width();
  var imgHeight = $(".flexslider li img").height();
  $('.flex-caption-viewport').width(imgWidth).height(imgHeight)
}).resize();
```

Another way should be to use `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(window).resize();
}, 100);
```

Comment: Same problem still exists. The height is set to 0px. It gotta have something to do with when everything is executed. However, I don't know how to get it to execute any later than it already is...